# derivative problem. is it same?

Tags: derivatives

First derivative of $y=\ln(x)^{\cos x}$ is $-\sin x\ln x+\frac{\cos x}{x}$ or another answer? My friend gets another answer, but it's true? thanks.

Comment: $\ln x^{\cos x}=\cos x\ln x$ or $[\ln x]^{\cos x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\ln (x)^{\cos x}=\ln\left(x^{\cos x}\right)$, we have
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln x^{\cos x}\right]=\frac{d}{dx}\left[(\cos x)\ln x\right]=(\cos x)\frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln x\right]+(\ln x)\frac{d}{dx}\left[\cos x\right] $$
$$ =(\cos x)\frac{1}{x}+(\ln x)(-\sin x)=\frac{\cos x}{x}-(\sin x)\ln x $$
If you meant to raise the function $\ln x$ by $\cos x$, then its best to write, $(\ln x)^{\cos x}$ as the parenthesis make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

$$y = e^{\ln (\ln(x))^{\cos x}} = e^{\cos x \ln (\ln(x))}$$

$$y^{'} = e^{\cos x \ln (\ln(x))} \cdot (\cos x \ln (\ln(x)))^{'} = e^{\cos x \ln (\ln(x))}  \cdot \left(-\sin x \ln (\ln(x)) + \cos x \frac{1}{\ln x} \frac{1}{x}\right)$$

$$=  (\ln(x))^{\cos x}\left(-\sin x \ln (\ln(x)) + \cos x \frac{1}{\ln x} \frac{1}{x}\right)$$

Comment: $$e^{\cos\left(x\right)\log\left|\log\left|x\right|\right|}\implies \log\left|x\right|^{\cos\left(x\right)} \left(-\sin\left(x\right)\log\left| \log\left|x\right|\right|+\cos\left(x\right)\frac{1}{x\log\left|x\right|}\right)$$

Comment: you re right . thanks! i will fix the error

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you mean $(\ln x)^{\cos x}$ and not $\ln(x^{\cos x})$.  I wish people would be explicit about that point.

If $g(x)$ is constant then $\dfrac d {dx} (f(x))^{g(x)} = g(x)f(x)^{g(x)-1}$.

If $f(x)$ is constant then $\dfrac d {dx} (g(x))^{g(x)} = f(g)^{g(x)} (\ln f(x)) f'(x)$.

If neither is constant then $\dfrac d {dx} (g(x))^{g(x)} = \text{the sum of those two things}$.

That can be proved by logarithmic differentiation.